# Handle or intercept new page event on a PDF table to draw a line

Tags: vb.net, itext

I am creating a PDF table and I can manage what happens when the table need more than one page as posted here:

[iTextsharp - draw a line at the end and start of a page with tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40620925/itextsharp-draw-a-line-at-the-end-and-start-of-a-page-with-tables)

If the table needs another page then I draw a final line on the actual page BEFORE the new page is inserted.

Now I need to draw a top line on the NEW page but I don't know to which method call. I'm trying something like this:

```vb
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf

Public Class LineaBottom
    Implements IPdfPTableEvent

    Public Sub TableLayout(table As PdfPTable, widths As Single()(), heights() As Single, headerRows As Integer, rowStart As Integer, canvases() As PdfContentByte) Implements IPdfPTableEvent.TableLayout
        'Throw New NotImplementedException()

        Dim columns As Integer
        Dim footer As Integer = widths.Length - table.FooterRows
        Dim header As Integer = table.HeaderRows - table.FooterRows + 1
        Dim ultima As Integer = footer - 1

        If last <> -1 Then
            Dim line As PdfContentByte
            line = pdfWrite.DirectContent
            line.SetLineWidth(0.5)
            line.MoveTo(xStart, curY)
            line.LineTo(xEnd, curY)
            line.Stroke()

            'canvases(PdfPTable.BASECANVAS).Rectangle(rect)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Where xStart and xEnd are global variables with left and right margin plus or minus a value.

**I don't know how to adapt the line**

```
canvases(PdfPTable.BASECANVAS).Rectangle(rect)
```

because that line was from a Java sample drawing a Rectangle and I need just a line

and the line

```
If last <> -1 Then
```

detects the last row of a page, **I need to detect the first row of the new page**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but:

- If I need to add something when a table is being split and *before* iTextSharp moves to a new page, I would not use a `IPdfPTableEvent`. Instead I would use a [IPdfPTableEventSplit](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPTableEventSplit.html)
- If I need to add something when the table is being split, *after* iTextSharp moves to a new page, and *before* the rest of the table is added, I would not use a `IPdfPTableEvent`. Instead I would use a [IPdfPTableEventAfterSplit](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPTableEventAfterSplit.html)

When creating the events, I would pass the `Document` and `PdfWriter` object. I would get the coordinates I need by asking that `Document` object for the dimensions of the current page, and I would use the `PdfWriter` to add the lines.

However, that's not an answer to your question. You seem to know how to draw a rectangle, but you don't know how to draw a line. That's simple:

```
PdfContentByte cb = canvases(PdfPTable.BASECANVAS)
cb.MoveTo(x1, y1)
cb.LineTo(x2, y2)
cb.Stroke()
```

You can change the all kinds of properties, for instance line width, like this:

```
PdfContentByte cb = canvases(PdfPTable.BASECANVAS)
cb.SaveState()
cb.SetLineDash(8, 4, 0)
cb.SetLineWidth(2.0f)
cb.MoveTo(x1, y1)
cb.LineTo(x2, y2)
cb.Stroke()
cb.RestoreState()
```

As for the values of `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, and `y2`, you have to define them based on the values passed to you through the `widths` and `heights` parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the support. I'm near to find the solution. If I use Dim cb As PdfContentByte and then  cb = canvases(PdfPTable.BASECANVAS) I get the error "canvases is not declared" and the same if first I use "Dim myCanvas As New Canvas()"  as referenced on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745163(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1 Do I need to import or declare  something before?