# How to get/return a boolean value from the Public Sub AfterSplitTable Event?

Tags: vb.net, itext

I create a table with a lot of rows.

```vb
txtCell1 = NameOfUser
Dim cell1 As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(txtCell1 , fontCell))
cell1.Border = 12
table.AddCell(cell1 )
```

`12` is for Border left and right

I'm using `table.TotalHeight` and `pdfWrite.GetVerticalPosition(False) - pdfDoc.BottomMargin` to manage what happens BEFORE the page break, drawing a inferior line at the end of the page.

Now I need to control the page break so when the table jump to the next page **the FIRST row of the new page will use `cellRectangleBorder` is 13** (Border left, right AND top)

A solution like this

```vb
txtCell1 = NameOfUser
Dim cell1 As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(txtCell1 , fontCell))
if newPage then cellRectangleBorder = 13
cell1.Border = cellRectangleBorder
table.AddCell(cell1 )
'Reset cellRectangleBorder to the normal value for the next rows...
cellRectangleBorder = 12
```

`newPage` a boolean value assigned on the `AfterSplitTable` event

The call to the class is

```vb
Dim table As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable(1)
table.TableEvent = New TopLine()
```

And the complete Class

```vb
Public Class TopLine
Implements IPdfPTableEventAfterSplit

    Private pdfPTableEventAfterSplit As IPdfPTableEventAfterSplit

    Public Sub AfterSplitTable(table As PdfPTable, startRow As PdfPRow, startIdx As Integer) Implements IPdfPTableEventAfterSplit.AfterSplitTable
    'Throw New NotImplementedException()

    Dim newPage As Boolean = True

    End Sub

    Public Sub SplitTable(table As PdfPTable) Implements IPdfPTableEventSplit.SplitTable
    Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub

    Public Sub TableLayout(table As PdfPTable, widths As Single()(), heights() As Single, headerRows As Integer, rowStart As Integer, canvases() As PdfContentByte) Implements IPdfPTableEvent.TableLayout
    Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub

End Class
```

But this code is not working, I never get the `newPage = True` when the new page starts and I don't know what is wrong, the call to the class or if I need to implement something more on the class to match `newPage` on the normal code with the value on the event.

Comment: All your handlers throw `NotImplementedException()`.

Comment: @GSerg I don´t understand. Even if I mark "Throw New NotImplementedException()" is the same. Can you please explain?

Comment: When you create a new class based on an interface and all the subs are created, but you still need to write code in the subs. The reason that the lines containing NotImplementedException are there, is so that, although the code will compile, if you try to execute any of those subs, an exception is thrown to remind you that you still need to write the code for them. In the sub you're trying to execute, comment out the 'Throw New NotImplementedException' line and try again.

Comment: @DavidWilson  Great explanation thanks. Even if i comment that line and on the body of the sub I just add MsgBox("Inside the Sub") the message never is displayed on screen.

Comment: Well as your code stands, it doesn't look like it will. Give me a few to have a look at the itextsharp library.

Comment: @DavidWilson Thanks, I only need the return of a boolean True just right afther the new page was inserted and before the rest of the Table

Comment: Sorry - I've run out of time. From what little I've looked at, it should work. Try putting the messagebox code in all the event subs and see if any of them are triggered - removing the 'Throw exception' lines of course. Sorry I cant be more help.

Comment: I did find this though - It might point you in the right direction. - http://cjhaas.com/blog/2014/07/28/handling-a-splitting-table-in-itextsharp/

Comment: This is the second question you posted about drawing content when splitting tables. All your questions sound really complicated. Maybe it would help if you took one step back and explain which end result you are trying to achieve. Maybe you want to do something that is really simple, but you seem to be making it very complicated.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie You're right Bruno. This is why now I take a more simple path. I only need to get a boolean variable with True when the new page event occurs. With that variable I can just modify the border style of the cells of the first row on the new page as explained here. No graphics or canvas involved, just one if then. I tested the code (without the new page event) and works fine, only need to solve the detection of the event. If you considered is ok I can delete or mark the other question as solved.

Comment: I am not familiar with VB code, but when you create `Dim newPage As Boolean = True` doesn't `newPage` go out of scope once `End Sub` is reached? I don't want to claim that I'm a better VB programmer than you are (I've never written VB code), but isn't it a newbie error to create `newPage` inside the subroutine instead of making `newPage` a member variable of the `TopLine` class? Your complex way of describing the requirement still confuses me: I still have no clue about what it is that you want to do. An image would do wonders.

Comment: Image https://i.stack.imgur.com/mI6fM.png I know how to draw the final line before the page break. I'm looking to "draw a line" or just change the border style of the first row of the new page (adding the top border). A note, even if I replace the line Dim newPage As Boolean = True with a msgbox("TEST INSIDE DE EVENT") the message is not displayed, so maybe is a trouble with the event itself. Sorry any inconvenience english is not my mother language

Comment: Here is how I found the solution for the line at the end of the page without using any event or class http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40620925/itextsharp-draw-a-line-at-the-end-and-start-of-a-page-with-tables